# Should i go with vb.net or VBA? Mostly working with excel files

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I'm starting a new job - my first - as a financial controller. The job will mean working a lot with excel files, for example formatting a document so that it can be imported and understood by other financial programs like SAP, or creating charts with the data in a document. There might be many specific tasks where vb.net/vba can come useful so I would really to be good at it.

My question is, should I do vb.net through visual studio or vba via Excel? My understanding is that you can achieve basically the same things with both in terms of excel-files, but perhaps vba is quicker and easier to learn and use. Vb.net on the other hand has a much better IDE through visual studio and learning it will give me a knowledge which can also be more useful elsewhere. Is this correct? Instead of trying one of them only to find out after some time that I should have gone with the other, I hope to get it right from the start.

Comment: Even if this question is not a good one for Stack Overflow, what I think is that you should go with VBA as soon as you work with Excel files - very used in financial controlling. VBA for Excel is already based on the Excel Object model while VB.NET is a general purpose language. So, even if VB.NET is (IMHO) more powerful than VBA, in your case VBA would be easier to use and especially to distribute (you only send the Excel file, no setup packages). But if you want to learn something on the .NET that would be more useful elsewhere, than rather than VB.NET I would go for C#.

Comment: Agree with Matteo above. VBA is the right tool for the job, but most likely you will need both in the long run, especially if you step away from the excel world.. If you hit a dead-end because of VBA's limitations, the next step is .NET. So I would allocate 80% of time learning VBA and 20% of time .NET initially. As you become more competent in VBA, you could allocate more time to .NET.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! I was unsure about posting the question here but I also thought the best answers would come from here. OK, so VBA is the way to go. I tried doing some VBA in excel last week and, having done other programming, I really became frustrated with the IDE which isn't very user friendly or customizable. Is there anything that can be done about that, for example using another IDE for the VBA development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use both VBA and VB.Net so I would recommend learning both.

Learning VBA is easier than learning VB.Net because there is so much less to learn.  I find VBA tutorials easier to master mainly because most VB.Net tutorials seem to be more concerned with demonstrating the amazing functionality of VB.net than teaching you the basics of the language.  Once you have VBA under your belt the learning curve to VB.Net is not too steep.

You access Excel workbooks from VB.Net using an interop which can read and write from any Excel version from 2003 onwards. It may be able to access earlier versions but I do not know any one who uses earlier versions so cannot test. The interop is slow. If your program is doing nothing but manipulate Excel worksheets, you are probably better using VBA.

VB.Net's forms have far more controls than VBA's. If you are trying to create an attractive, flexible, adjustable user interface then VB.Net is the one to choose.

VB.Net is compiled to an immediate language which is then compiled to machine code at runtime to take advantage of the capabilities of the machine it is running on.  VBA compiles to an immediate language which is interpreted at runtime.  For heavy processing, VB.Net programs can be thousands of time faster than VBA macros.

VB.Net creates executable programs (MyProgram.exe) which can run on any Windows machine making them easy to distribute if necessary.  VBA macros run within Excel so the user need to have and open Excel to run them.

To summarise: start with VBA but then try VB.Net once you have mastered the syntax.

Comment: Thank you, Tony! Ok, I'll start with VBA. Too bad about the IDE. I will try to install office 32-bit on my 64-bit to use MZ-tools, that might improve the IDE.

Comment: I would also suggest [Rubberduck](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck) as a good tool to help with some of the gotchas of VBA.

Comment: This is a must to check out - thank you, and hope and think this post will be of use to others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect. VBA is far faster has it runs in process. All calls are marshalled into network protocols to be sent cross process.

Plus you have to load COM with VBA. To use Excel you have to load COM. To use VB.NET with Excel you load COM and .NET - a far bigger resource load.

The code would be almost identical.